# Can I append to a css background url in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a background for multiple divs that is like so:

`background: url('assets/bg_01.jpg');`

each having their own number 01 - 10. Now I want to append to the URL in jquery when a button is clicked to change it to `bg_01_active.jpg`, etc.  Is it possible to append to the url with a variable, or would I have to set it manually for each div?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "append to the Url"?

Comment: I want to add the word "_active" to the filename so that when a button is clicked, it changes the background image to the active version in Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="asset_buttons" id="bg_01" style="background-image:  url('assets/bg_01.jpg');">Test</div>

$(".asset_buttons").click(function() {    
    $(this).css("background", "url('assets/" + $(this).attr('id')  + "_active.jpg')");
});
```

So you would have 10 divs with the same class, but varying ids based on their number.
The JQuery snippet will change the background url of each of the buttons as you click based on their ids.

Comment: You could combine this with Dasein's solution, namely the split part, for more efficiency!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking (you want to change the background url on a button click?), it can be done like this

```
<div class='class', id='id'> </div>
$('.class' //or '#id').on('click', function() {
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(newer)');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mahmudzero/anLL1uop/28/

Answer (score 0):

Of course you don't have to do it manually. Otherwise, what is programming for?

```
 var src = "url('assets/bg_01.jpg')".split(".");
 $(element).css('background-image', src[0] + "_active." + src[1]);
```

Comment: I have multiple Divs, with similar filenames, would I have to state their name in the variable?

In your example that only will affect bg_01.jpg and bg_01_active.jpg, how would I do it for bg_02.jpg ---> bg_10.jpg?

Comment: You didn't post any code so I used just general examples.

Comment: ``"url('assets/bg_01.jpg')".split(".");`` could be ``yourvar.split(".");``